# Best practice for unit testing Ember.js util with dependent util

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember util that I want to unit test. It uses another util.

```
// utils/util-1.js
import util2 from './util-2';

export default util1() {
  util2();
}
```

I want to somehow mock the referenced util. Since it's not an `Ember.Object`, I can't take advantage of the service injecting system. I'm familiar with node `require` mocking, but I don't think I can use that here. The best I can come up with is:

```
// utils/util-1.js
export default util1(util2) {
  util2();
}
```

Anyone have anything better to share?